# IE browser gets shrunk during execution

Tags: selenium, internet-explorer, selenium-webdriver, browser

I am facing an weird issue. I have a selenium suite to execute on multiple browsers. It works fine of chrome and Firefox. But in case of IE, the web page under test gets shrunk (web page resize) making elements hidden. Hence facing NoSuchElementException. 
I have already tried executing on full screen. No help.

Please help in solving this issue.

Thanks,
Praveen

Comment: Your code trials and relevant HTML?

Comment: @DebanjanB Sorry, I cannot provide the code, as it is confidential. The issue is actually with browser, not with the code.

Comment: try this :  DesiredCapabilities caps = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
  caps.setCapability("ignoreZoomSetting", true);
  WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(caps);

Comment: @cruisepandey No. Still facing the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know the exact reason for that, however, suggested workaround would be to implement pre-execution method for your test which would take care of all your browser different configurations. For example, if you are using Java with Selenium and JUnit5, it might be:

```
@BeforeEach
void beforeTestExecution() {
        DesiredCapabilities desiredCapabilities = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
        desiredCapabilities.setCapability(
                CapabilityType.ForSeleniumServer.ENSURING_CLEAN_SESSION, true);
        driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(desiredCapabilities);

        // Navigate to URL
        driver.get("http://www.yoursite.com");

        // Maximize your website window before test.
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
}
```

Or:

```
@BeforeEach
void configBrowser() {
        DesiredCapabilities desiredCapabilities = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
        desiredCapabilities.setCapability(
                CapabilityType.ForSeleniumServer.ENSURING_CLEAN_SESSION, true);
        driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(desiredCapabilities);

        // Start Internet Explorer maximized.
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
}
```